# Netbeans Not Recognizing Members of sockaddr_in - C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans

My Netbeans installation on Ubuntu is not recognizing any members of structure sockaddr_in.

Code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

// Later in the code

sockaddr_in serverAddress;
memset(&serverAddress, '0', sizeof(serverAddress));
serverAddress.sin_family = INADDR_ANY;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(config.port);
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Netbeans is showing the red curly lines under sin_family, sin_port and sin_addr saying `Unable to resolve identifier sin_family`. When I compile it (GCC) it works just fine.

Comment: do you #include <string.h> for memset? sockaddr_in is defined in <netinet/in.h>go there and check

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain Sorry, yeah, that's included

Comment: but does it compile? is it compilation error or just code assistance issue?

Comment: check in project properties what is a tool collecion you use. Probably default GNU, and then in Tools->Options->C/C++->Code assistance check that you have path to usr/include or wherever you have this file located

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain It's a code assistance issue. My tool collection is GNU and the `usr/include` path is indeed in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Right click on your Project in the `Project Explorer,` go to `Code Assistance` and click on `Reparse Project`.